# Is that really the author sitting in on her character's lecture?

Tags: cameo, a-discovery-of-witches

*A Discovery of Witches* episode 1, Diana Bishop is giving a lecture on the history of science. In the audience, sitting next to Gillian (herself an unlikely person to show up for a lecture on alchemy, as Diana later remarks), there's a lady who looks suspiciously like Deborah Harkness. Did the author have a cameo in the first episode of the TV adaptation of her books?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. According to [Ms. Harkness' page on IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3894489/?ref_=nv_sr_1?ref_=nv_sr_1), she was a "Lecture Attendee" in episode 1.1.